# Рандомные числа в Python 3: выбирать рандомные значения из массива целых чисел до тех пор, пока эти значения не кончатся

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Хотел бы, чтобы вы помогли решить проблему, суть такова:
Есть код, цель которого - выбирать рандомные значения из массива групп до тех пор, пока эти значения, собственно, не кончатся. Код таков:

```
import vk, csv, random

session = vk.Session()
api = vk.API(session)  

with open('current_groups_2.csv', 'r') as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)  
    reader = map(int, f)  
    group_list = list(reader)  


if random.choice(group_list) > 0:  
    x = random.choice(group_list)

photo = api.groups.getById(group_id = x, fields = 'members_count')

print(sorted(photo))
```

Пока что переменной x присваивается одно значение. Как заставить программу после каждого прохождения выбирать новое значение x?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [What is the most pythonic way to pop a random element from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10048069/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048069/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-pop-a-random-element-from-a-list

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить все элементы из списка в случайном порядке:

```
random.shuffle(group_list)
for group_id in group_list:
    #...
```

Answer (score 1):

если group_list обновляется во время работы:

```
while group_list:
    # случайный индекс group_list
    i = random.randrange(len(group_list))
    # поменять местами случайный индекс и последний элемент
    group_list[i], group_list[-1] = group_list[-1], group_list[i]
    x = group_list.pop()  # pop последний элемент O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то, что Вам нужно, то сначала нужно перемешать список **group_list**, потом извлекать из него последний элемент в цикле до тех пор, пока список не станет пустым. Получим рандомную последовательность всех значений списка. Код такой:

```
import vk, csv, random

session = vk.Session()
api = vk.API(session)

with open('current_groups_2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader = map(int, f)
    group_list = list(reader)


random.shuffle(group_list)

while group_list:
    x = group_list.pop()

    photo = api.groups.getById(group_id = x, fields = 'members_count')

    print(sorted(photo))
```

Так как список перемешан случайным образом, метод **pop** каждый раз будет возвращать элемент со случайным содержимым и удалять его же из списка. Поскольку элемент удаляется с конца списка, то при удалении элемента пересчет индексов элементов списка не производится и код работает эффективно.
Далее внутри этого же блока кода (внутри тела цикла) что-то делаем с полученным элементом.